# Rspec: How to check randomization using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I want to test this method using rspec:

```
ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(User.order("RANDOM()").where(:sex => "f").limit(10)).as_json
```

Using factory girl I created some users

```
FactoryGirl.create_list(:user, 15)
```

How to check if the method returns a random result? Thanks

Comment: What method do you want to test and what is its definition? Your first code snippet was a Ruby expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of principal, unit-testing should be deterministic. You could use statistical models to test that the result is somehow random, but this means that your tests will *sometimes* fail (1,2,3,4... is a valid random result too!).

What exactly are you trying to test? You want to see whether `postgresql`s random method is random? This is out-of-scope for unit testing.  The best thing I can offer you is to expect calling `order("RANDOM()")`, although this, also might be a bit superfluous:

```
expect(User).to receive(:order).with('RANDOM()').and_return(User)
```